# Team City - Report software versions on each agent

Tags: teamcity

We have a Team City setup with ~10 agents. I was tasked with finding out what versions of software is installed on each agent, more specially git.

Is there a way I can gather this information as a Team City admin? Can I execute a command such as `git --version` on each agent and view the results?

The other option is to log onto each server and run the command, but that is time consuming and no efficient.

We are using **2022.10.1**

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could create a build configuration with one command line runner step which execute, for example:

```
git --version > git_version.txt
```

and save generated txt to artifacts

Then, via run custom build you could run your configuration across all agents via one click